# OAuth not working after deploying to Azure [ASP.NET MVC]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth

I'm trying to integrate OAuth in my [Web App](http://shibpurconnect.azurewebsites.net). It's working fine when testing it through localhost. But after publishing to Azure its not working. Getting Http 500 error for http://shibpurconnect.azurewebsites.net/Account/ExternalLoginCallback

I have already updated all the redirect urls in Google, Facebok. Please see attached screenshot -
[image]
[image]

Looks like I'm missing some configuration, but not sure what.

Thanks for looking into it and appreciate your help.

Comment: Are you using some kind of logging system like Elmah? Isn't any error logged in the server?

Comment: Thanks @AugustoBarreto for your help. I added Elmah and able to track down the problem. It was giving me login error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I integrated Elmah and able to get the actual reason. It was due to login failure to database.

Answer (score 0):

500 is internal server error. So something went wrong in the function ExternalLoginCallback when it was executed on the server. What I do is create a simple error Controller, then I could put a try / catch around the code in AccountController.cs -> ExternalLoginCallback and redirect to ErrorController from inside the catch. after I log & display the error from the ErrorController.